# Realizar Consulta dentro de un while

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quiero realizar la consulta dentro del while para cada `idpedido` y mostrar en una columna de la tabla el resultado, no funciona. ¿Dónde debería poner la consulta? El bucle while ahora mismo no funciona. Si alguien tiene otra idea para resolver el problema. Gracias por la ayuda.

```html
<h1>Pedidos</h1>
             <?php
            
            
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE idempleado = '$idcliente' OR idcocinero='$idcliente'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta );                     
            $consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM linea_pedido WHERE idpedido IN (SELECT idpedido FROM pedidos WHERE idempleado = '$idcliente' OR idcocinero='$idcliente')";
            $resultado3 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta2 );
            
            ?>
          
    <table borde='2'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Idpedido</th>
                <th>Pedido</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Idempleado</th>
                <th>Idcocinero</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
            while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))  
            { 
            $consulta4 = "SELECT SUM(Precio) as Importe FROM productos WHERE idProducto IN (SELECT idProducto FROM linea_pedido WHERE idpedido= $columna['idpedido'];)";
            $resultado4 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta4 );
            ?>
                <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['idpedido']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['pedido']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['estado']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['idempleado']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['idcocinero']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $resultado4['Importe']; ?></td>
                   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="eliminar('<?= $columna['idpedido'] ?>')">Eliminar Pedido</button></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Cuando decís _no funciona_, ¿no itera el bucle? ¿se estanca? ¿da error?

Comment: Puedes sacar a un array todos los pedidos que necesites, por ejemplo realizando la consulta con un IN ($pedidos), y de esta forma solo con una consulta obtienes el resultado en un array y lo recorres dentro del while, evitando realizar tantas llamadas a BBDD.

Comment: porque no hacer un inner join??

Comment: La consulta esta bien, el problema es que al poner la consulta dentro del bucle, el bucle no se ejecuta correctamente. Veis algún error o el motivo por el qué ocurre?

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Dentro del bucle y despues de la consulta no estas obteniendo la fila que retorna la consulta por ejemplo con `$sum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado4)` por lo que cuando haces `$resultado4['Importe']` estas tratando de acceder a un objeto `mysqli_result` no a los datos en si mismos

Comment: ¿Tienes algo para compartir con la comunidad? De lo contrario, siéntete en libertad de borrar tu pregunta.

Comment: $consulta4 = "SELECT SUM(Precio) as Importe FROM productos WHERE idProducto IN (SELECT idProducto FROM linea_pedido WHERE idpedido=$columna['idpedido'])";

Comment: Las llaves del while no funcionan, y da este error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING), hay un error en el acceso a la variable idpedido pero no entiendo como debería ponerla.